# How can I change the flashlight intensity on my Pixel 6?

Tags: settings, google-pixel-6, flashlight

I wonder how I can change the flashlight intensity on my Google Pixel 6.

Comment: With root you should have access to pseudo files with paths like `led:flash_0/max_brightness`, `led:torch_0/max_brightness` and/or `torch-light0/max_brightness` in `/sys/class/leds/`. Change values inside them and test. Scale is usually 0-255 or 1-1000. Some custom ROM and root apps have GUI settings for the same.

Answer (score 1):

Flash Android 13 Developer Preview on your device. “getTorchStrengthLevel” and “turnOnTorchWithStrengthLevel” is only available from Android 13.

Answer (score 1):

If you have Android 13 installed there are two apps I know that support flashlight dimming functionality:

- [FlashDim](https://github.com/cyb3rko/flashdim) (developed by myself :D )
- [Tiramisu Flashlight](https://github.com/polodarb/Flashlight-Tiramisu)